# How to use expect.to.throw with Mocha and Chai?

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to write integration tests with Mocha and Chai but Chai doesn't seem to catch the errors.

Code being tested:

```js
export async function createUser(
  username: string,
  password: string,
): Promise < {} > {
  const user = await User.findOne({
    username
  })
  if (user) {
    throw new UserInputError('Username is taken', {
      errors: {
        username: 'Username is taken',
      },
    })
  }

  if (username.trim() === '' || null) {
    throw new UserInputError('Must not be empty', {
      errors: {
        username: 'Must not be empty',
      },
    })
  }

  const hash = crypto.createHash('sha512').update(password).digest('hex')

  const newUser = new User({
    username,
    password: hash,
  })

  return newUser.save()
}
```

And the test code :

```js
it('Fails when no username is provided', () => {
  const password = uuid()

  expect(async() => {
    await client.mutate({
      mutation: gql `
              mutation($username: String!, $password: String!){
                createUser(username: $username, password: $password) {
                  id
                  username
                }
              }
            `,
      variables: {
        username: '',
        password,
      },
    })
  }).to.throw()
})
```

I expect the test to pass, but the code I have fails with the following error message:

```
  AssertionError: expected [Function] to throw an error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `to.throw()` expects a function but using `async`, you return a `Promise`.

So you have tu use `.to.be.rejected` instead of `to.throw()`.

You need [chai-as-promised](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/) and you can try something like this:

```js
it('Fails when no username is provided', () => {
    expect(client.mutate({...})).to.be.rejected;
});
```

Don't use `async/await` into `expect` because `chai` will handle it.

Also, you can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50412182/using-chai-expect-throw-not-catching-promise-rejection)